# How to make Mac Terminal path shorter?

Tags: macos, terminal

Is it possible to make my Terminal path shorter?

Is it possible to make it so it only shows the current directory?

Comment: Here is how to do it in bash:

http://superuser.com/questions/60555/show-only-current-directory-name-not-full-path-on-bash-prompt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this in the terminal

```
export PS1='\W$ '
```

Comment: Before I go ahead is there a way back after this?

Comment: It is temporary so you can just close the Terminal. To have it stick add that line you your `~/.profile` file. The original PS1 is `PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '`

Answer (score 4):

The variable `PS1` defines your path lookup.

For example:

```
 export PS1="\u@\h \w> "
```

gives

```
  username@host /full/path/to/directory>

  export PS1="\u@\h \W> "
```

gives

```
   username@host directory>
```

Now you could also do

```
 export PS1="\u@\h  [\$(Some command with output)]> "
```

You will have to edit your ~/.bash_profile. So it is loaded on startup.
thus put export `PS1=....` in .bash_profile

Restarting the terminal will revert all your edits, so that is why you put it into ~/.bash_profile